# whitespace next to embedded tiktok

Tags: html, css, flexbox, embed

I have embedded a tiktok onto my site using the copy embed code on the tiktok, and I am happy with the layout of it on desktop screen. However, in mobile screen, I have used flex-direction: colun but this has caused some white space on both sides of the tiktok, i would like to get rid of this please, does anyone know how to?

```
<div class="luxx-tiktok">

  <p>LUXX RENO</p>

<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@luxxxreno/video/6999301519010958597" data-video-id="6999301519010958597" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@luxxxreno" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@luxxxreno">@luxxxreno</a> <p>1 v Verdansk | CC: @louicm_  <a title="warzone" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/warzone">##warzone</a> <a title="luxxmob" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/luxxmob">##luxxmob</a> <a title="callofduty" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/callofduty">##callofduty</a> <a title="warzonebestclips" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/warzonebestclips">##warzonebestclips</a></p> <a target="_blank" title="♬ original sound - Luxx Reno" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/original-sound-6999301469555919622">♬ original sound - Luxx Reno</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```

```
<p>AVERAGEANT</p>


<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@averageant_/video/7000467213442436358" data-video-id="7000467213442436358" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@averageant_" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@averageant_">@averageant_</a> <p>These doors are abit weird <a title="luxxmob" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/luxxmob">##luxxmob</a> <a title="edits" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/edits">##edits</a> <a title="viral" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/viral">##viral</a> <a title="gaming" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/gaming">##gaming</a> <a title="warzoneclips" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/warzoneclips">##warzoneclips</a></p> <a target="_blank" title="♬ original sound - Ant" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/original-sound-7000467080210320133">♬ original sound - Ant</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```

```
<p>SPODERBRAD</p>

<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@spoderbrad/video/7000351531686022405" data-video-id="7000351531686022405" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@spoderbrad" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@spoderbrad">@spoderbrad</a> <p>Who wants to run some games? <a title="callofduty" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/callofduty">##callofduty</a> <a title="bradspoder" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/bradspoder">##bradspoder</a> <a title="luxxmob" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/luxxmob">##luxxmob</a> <a title="warzone" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/warzone">##warzone</a></p> <a target="_blank" title="♬ original sound - Streamer | SpoderBrad" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/original-sound-7000351296293292805">♬ original sound - Streamer | SpoderBrad</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```

```
<p>KEEZO</p>

<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@kkeezo/video/6997128140489362694" data-video-id="6997128140489362694" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@kkeezo" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@kkeezo">@kkeezo</a> <p>how a 4KD player uses hacks! <a title="luxxmob" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/luxxmob">##luxxmob</a> <a title="cod" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/cod">##cod</a> <a title="codclips" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/codclips">##codclips</a> <a title="warzone" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/warzone">##warzone</a> <a title="warzonebestclips" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/warzonebestclips">##warzonebestclips</a></p> <a target="_blank" title="♬ My Potna Dem - $ILKMONEY" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/My-Potna-Dem-6776999844323002370">♬ My Potna Dem - $ILKMONEY</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>
```